# Can arrays be stored in an ASP.NET profile?

Tags: asp.net

Imagine an ASP.NET website which displays stock prices when a user logs in.  Can the list of stock ticker symbols be stored in an ASP.NET profile?  I only see how to add strings, etc., and not collections like Lists or arrays.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To avoid over-engineering, for this particular case you could just do `"MSFT|AAPL|ETC"` and `string.Split('|')` the value. `string.Join("|", values)` to store.

If you *do* run into a situation where you need an object graph that's actually complex, you [can do](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8b58y5d%28VS.85%29.aspx):

```
<profile defaultProvider="AspNetSqlProfileProvider">
  <properties>
    <add name="FavoriteURLs" 
      type="System.Collection.Specialized.StringCollection"
      serializeAs="Xml" />
  </properties>
</profile>
```

The only requirement here being that the object specified in "type" must be XML serializable.

Answer (score 2):

You can use other types other than strings....

Here's an MSDN article on it:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8b58y5d(VS.85).aspx